# Slow RVM initialization with cygwin on a 64bit machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cygwin, rvm, windows-7-x64

I am imagining that this might get me dinged for asking such a non-specific question but I'm getting desperate at this point. I'm using cygwin (I'm a bash addict) on a Windows 7 machine with huge memory and processor speed. For some reason when I do anything with RVM I get a 30 second delay before it happens. This includes but is not limited to rvm use, cding into a directory that has RVM in it and actually cding back OUT of those directories.

When this huge delay occurs I get the most insane forking of bash in my process explorer. bash processes are forked off and then disappear rapidly during the 30 seconds. I can't figure out how to really dig into this and see what is happening.

What I'm hoping someone can help me with is directing me toward resources that might address this issue (yes, I've Googled a lot and haven't found what I need--and I'm still looking) or even have had experience with this themselves.

thank you in advance and please be gentle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since windows doesn't have a native equivalent of fork, cygwin must emulate it, so it will probably be a lot slower than on a real Unix OS.

See this thread:
http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2008-05/msg00360.html

Also at least one person has reported that forking on cygwin 1.7 is slower than 1.5:
http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-09/msg00871.html

Does your development require Windows, or can you do your work in  a VM instead?

Comment: Good answer, thanks. I've moved to using Ubuntu (latest stable) inside VirtualBox and that straightened everything right out.  thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't call that a good answer. Some of us have to put up with some realities, one of which is staying with Windows. I would call a good answer a real recipe on how to accelerate Rails start up on Cygwin x64. I googled for hours about this and frankly this is the only article whose title looked promising at all. Turned out to be a false positive. Meh.

Comment: What I've been led to believe is that because RVM is not designed to run on Windows this is a case of trying to force a square peg into a round whole. I felt this answer confirmed that in a rational manner and I was forced to make a tactical decision based upon the thoughts. It wasn't an answer I would have preferred per se, but that's life.  I've moved entirely to Ubuntu and the whole thing became moot. I understand that you have to stay with windows but I didn't have that restriction so it served my purposes. That's why I accepted it...

Comment: @dimitko Have you tried https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv ? I don't have cygwin anymore so I can't test; I'm guessing rbenv does less forking than rvm.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work in Windows?
According to the [FAQ](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/support/faq/), rvm is not intended to work on Windows. 
You should use [pik](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik) to get similar behaviour in Windows (although it misses the gemsets, it allows you to switch between ruby-versions, and with pik each rubyversion has its own set of gems).

Comment: Actualy RVM *does* work in Windows, simply because Cygwin emulates UNIX environment. Plus, it's tried and tested for long time now; RVM does indeed run well under Cygwin.